# What if canvas drawing changes while toDataURL is running

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a for loop. In this loop I draw to `canvas` and then to `toDataURL` on it. The `toDataURL` function is asynchronus. So the for loop continues to the next iteration and it does another drawing and then calls its toDataURL again for that. Is this a race condition? In my tests everything is working fine, the data url of each iteration of the loop is correct, but this just might be my computer, so I just wanted to ask.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think `toDataURL` is asynchronous?

Comment: @levi correctly implies that toDataURL is synchronous so it will block loops (including requestAnimationFrame) until it completes. No worries about race conditions :-)